# Props not being passed through Route element with React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
                    <Route path="roles" element={<Dashboard role={true}  />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>


    )

}
```

Console logging props.role from the Dashboard component gives me undefined. I've looked at 20 threads on this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Dashboard component in jsfiddle cause Stackoverflow won't let me edit the post with all of it in here. It's a template from Material UI

https://jsfiddle.net/j4xo0yuv/

Comment: Please share all relevant code. Can we see this `Dashboard` component? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I added it to the OP

Comment: Your `Dashboard` component isn't proxying any props forward to your `DashboardContent` component, so `props.role` is undefined in `DashboardContent`. Is this jsfiddle a complete code example, or just some extra code? I don't see the router or any console logs. Either way, voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Oh my god how did I miss that lol

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking through your code the issue is that you have this:

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    return <DashboardContent />;
}
```

If you take a look the component that you're setting as the Route element is Dashboard but actually the one where you're printing the `props.role` is the DashboardContent so you need to do this and pass the role to the DashboardContent:

```
export default function Dashboard(props) {
    return <DashboardContent role={props.role} />;
}
```